# How to make this drop overlay's fade-in animation work well?

Tags: wpf, animation, drag-and-drop

I have a simple MainWindow with a root Grid that contains Grid and in it a cell with a Button, and the root grid also contains an overlay control (control with partially transparent background and some short text like Drop here...). This full-window overlay shows up with a fade-in animation when the user drags a file over the window. The problem is my animation does not finish, it almost does not start, and repeats itself while the user drags the file over the window.

I am not sure where to look next. The DropOverlay class and XAML looks well. I think the problem is in the d&d event handling. When I use  IsHitTestVisible="False" it seems to work better when I do not have an animation.

## DropOverlay

### XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="cs_wpf_test_16.DropOverlay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_16"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Style="{DynamicResource BorderStyle1}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl" x:Key="BorderStyle1">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Background="#99000000">
        <Viewbox>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="100" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="50" Margin="15,0,0,0" Name="MyTextBlock">Drop Here...</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

### Code-behind

Nothing special.

## MainWindow

### XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="cs_wpf_test_16.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cs_wpf_test_16"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="209.375" Width="317.969"
        PreviewDragEnter="MyWindow_DragEnter"
        PreviewDragLeave="MyWindow_DragLeave"
        PreviewDrop="MyWindow_Drop"
        AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button>Test</Button>
        </Grid>
        <local:DropOverlay Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="MyDropOverlay"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Code-behind

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal bool _DraggingOver = false;
    internal bool DraggingOver
    {
        get
        {
            return _DraggingOver;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_DraggingOver != value)
            {
                _DraggingOver = value;
                UpdateDropIndicator();
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDropIndicator()
    {
        if (DraggingOver)
        {
            MyDropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            MyDropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private void MyWindow_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) &&
            !(e.Source is DropOverlay))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;

            var paths = e.Data.
                GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

            string path = paths[0];

            DraggingOver = true;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DraggingOver = false;

            //e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void MyWindow_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetVisualParent<DropOverlay>(e.Source) == null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        string[] paths = null;

        if (e.Effects != DragDropEffects.None &&
            e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            paths = e.Data.
                GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
        }

        DraggingOver = false;

        if (paths != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Dropped.");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void MyWindow_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetVisualParent<DropOverlay>(e.Source) == null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        if (p.X < 0 || p.Y < 0 ||
            p.X > ActualWidth || p.Y > ActualHeight)
        {
            DraggingOver = false;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : System.Windows.Media.Visual
    {
        var child = childObject as System.Windows.DependencyObject;
        // iteratively traverse the visual tree
        while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
        {
            child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        }
        return child as T;
    }
}
```

Expected result: the fade-in animation runs and finishes one time when the user starts dragging a file over the window.

Actual result: the fade-in animation does not finish, it starts over and over again and runs just up to some point where it is hardly visible that the overlay is there. Sometimes when I leave the window with the mouse while dragging the overlay fades-in nicely (but not in the good moment), sometimes not.

## Screenshots

[image: screenshot with the problem]

[image: screenshot with the drop overlay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it just **delete** your else case in **MyWindow_DragEnter**

copy the code below and paste instead of your MyWindow_DragEnter method.

in case you are lazy :)

```
    private void MyWindow_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) &&
            !(e.Source is DropOverlay))
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;

            var paths = e.Data.
                GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

            string path = paths[0];

            DraggingOver = true;

            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

**FOR FADE IN/OUT ANIMATIONS**

The problem is your UserControl  is set to Collapsed while animating => we need "connected animations" (one animation after another)

in our case we need some independent boolen: i took Selector.IsSelected.

Change your UpdateDropIndicator method

```
        private void UpdateDropIndicator()
        {
            if (DraggingOver)
            {
                Selector.SetIsSelected(MyDropOverlay, true);
                //   MyDropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                Selector.SetIsSelected(MyDropOverlay, false);
                //MyDropOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

and your xaml animation

```
             <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                 From="0" 
                                                 To="1" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0:0:0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                 From="1" 
                                                 To="0" 
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0:0:0.5">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
```

Comment: @silviubogan that actually needs some extra work on your bindings. you have to bind to your Opacity Property instead of Visibility. I'll try to make my own test version and post it.

Comment: @silviubogan The problem is that your UserControl is Collapsed while animating.